# Convert BioPython.Phylo distance matrix to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, biopython, phylogeny

I am wanting to convert a `Phylo.TreeConstruction.DistanceMatrix` into a `pandas` dataframe but can not work out how to do it. Does anyone know how?

```py
    alignment = AlignIO.read(align, "fasta")
    calculator = DistanceCalculator('identity', )
    dismat = calculator.get_distance(alignment)
```

Comment: Under the hood, the matrix consists of a list of names and a list of lists of numbers. You could try using `dismat.names` and `dismat.matrix` in the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor.

Comment: Oh excellent this works perfectly! Only give the bottom diagonal but that is all you need I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shortened version of @Lamma 's answer above. More elegant, but not sure if it offers computational improvements.

```
dismatDF = pd.DataFrame(list(distances))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but feels very dirty:

```py
for disLis in dismat:
      distances.append(disLis)
dismatDF = pd.DataFrame(distances)
```

It is taking each list in the `Phylo` object and appending it into a list of list then making a dataframe of this.